# Object of Type 'Dense' has no len()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I try to create a CNN model, but always get this error message.

> Error: TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)  in () ----> 1 model = simple_conv_model() 5 frames /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py in build_map(tensor, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer, node_index, tensor_index) 1345 1346 # Propagate to all previous tensors connected to this node. -> 1347 for i in range(len(node.inbound_layers)): 1348 x = node.input_tensors[i] 1349 layer = node.inbound_layers[i] TypeError: object of type 'Dense' has no len()

This is the model:

```
def simple_conv_model():
        input_layer=layers.Input(shape=(64,64,3), name="input_layer")    
        model=layers.Conv2D(16,3, activation="relu", padding='same', name="first_block_conv", strides=(1,1)) (input_layer)
        model=layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2), name="first_block_pooling") (model)
        model=layers.BatchNormalization(name="first_block_bn") (model)

        model=layers.Conv2D(32,3, activation="relu", padding='same', name="second_block_conv", strides=(1,1)) (input_layer)
        model=layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2), name="second_block_pooling") (model)
        model=layers.BatchNormalization(name="second_block_bn") (model)

        model=layers.Conv2D(64,3, activation="relu", padding='same', name="third_block_conv", strides=(1,1)) (input_layer)
        model=layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2), name="third_block_pooling") (model)
        model=layers.BatchNormalization(name="third_block_bn") (model)

        model=layers.Flatten() (model)
        model=layers.Dense(16, activation="relu", name="dense_1") (model)
        model=layers.BatchNormalization() (model)
        model=layers.Dropout(0.5, name="drop_out_dense_1") (model)

        model=layers.Dense(4, activation="relu", name="dense_2") (model)

        model=layers.Dense(1, activation="linear") (model)

        model_cnn = Model(input_layer, model)
        model_cnn.compile(loss="mean_absolute_percentage_error", optimizer="adam")

        return model_cnn

    model = simple_conv_model()
```

Comment: Error:

TypeError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-ac35d50d2fc0> in <module>()
----> 1 model = simple_conv_model()

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py in build_map(tensor, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer, node_index, tensor_index)
   1345 
   1346         # Propagate to all previous tensors connected to this node.
-> 1347         for i in range(len(node.inbound_layers)):
   1348             x = node.input_tensors[i]
   1349             layer = node.inbound_layers[i]

TypeError: object of type 'Dense' has no len()

Comment: Please include the traceback in the question itself, you can always edit your own question. Make sure that the traceback is complete.

Answer (score 5):

I also face this problem before because I import library from tensorflow.python.keras. Just change to use keras instead

Answer (score 0):

You are probably mistakenly using `input_layer` as the input of all the three `Conv2D` layers, whereas it is very likely that you intended to write something like this:

```
model = layers.Conv2D(16,3,...)(input_layer) # this is correct
# ...
model = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, ...)(model)  # pass `model` here as input
# ...
model = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, ...)(model)  # pass `model` here as input
```

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure he did that on purpose: he's doing an inception network (as am I and I'm also having this problem)

Answer (score 0):

I used the get the same error even for making a simple network using feature layer and functional API. On the opposite side from @patacharapon,

I replaced

```
import keras
```

here the keras version is `2.3.1`

to

```
from tensorflow import keras
```

while here the keras version is `2.3.0-tf`

Answer (score 0):

I replaced keras.models to tensorflow.keras.models and it worked for me.

Earlier:

```
from keras.models import Model
```

After Replacement:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
```

Answer (score -1):

The correct solution is provided here: https://www.programmersought.com/article/14464784093/
Namely import the model from tendorflow.keras.models instead of keras.models