# Using tf.keras.layers with keras.model

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

yes I've read everywhere that keras and tf.keras aren't compatible. But you can pass tf.keras.layers into a keras model, and it **does work.** When I try to do that with my own models... it does not work!

If you examine the resnet sourcecode for Resnet50.py, they build models like

```
input = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
x = layers.Dense()(x)
model = Model(input,x)
```

and it works fine whether you pass in layers=tf.keras.layers or layers=keras.layers

demonstration code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras

# THIS WORKS!
input_shape = (224,224,3)
base_model = keras.applications.ResNet50(layers=tf.keras.layers, weights='imagenet',
                  weights='imagenet', include_top=False, pooling=None,
                  input_shape=input_shape,
                  classes=1000)

# this fails!!
input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1000,activation='relu')(input)
model = keras.Model(input, x)
```

My code produces this error: type error:
    object of type Dense has no len

How to make my this work? Apparently there is a way to make it work, because the keras.applications prebuilt models do seem to support it and it works fine

I want to use tf.keras.layers because their batchnormalization layer works different. This is potentially the easiest way to drop it into our massive existing code base.

I do see this related stackoverflow post with the same error: [Object of Type 'Dense' has no len()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57585900/object-of-type-dense-has-no-len)

They correctly mention it's due to tf.keras and keras not being compatible. but again, I've confirmed that passing tf.keras.layers into keras.applications.resnet50 **does** return a keras model with the correct layers. Somehow.

Comment: No, you got it wrong, keras.applications uses models.Model, so it detects if you use tf.keras or keras and gets the corresponding modules. It is not mixing keras.and tf.keras, it just supports both

Comment: This greatly helps me, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the wrong conclusion, `keras.applications` is a module that supports both `keras` and `tf.keras` packages, as `keras.applications` uses `models.Model`, it detects if you use `tf.keras` or `keras` and gets the corresponding modules so the code is agnostic to the actual keras implementation.

`keras.applications` is not mixing usage of `keras` and `tf.keras`, it just supports both.